# Calling reloadData on same UITableView, but it seems like it's calling on a different one

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

This has been a headache for few hours now and I finally found out what is actually happening, but I don't know how to solve this issue.

I've got List.h with UITableView properly connected from storyboard:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Then there's List.m where I set delegates and datasource for my UITableView:

```
// Set tableview datasource and register class for cell reuse
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

// Set tableview delegate
self.tableView.delegate = self;

// Set tableview cells style
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:1.0f];

// Set tableview frame
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 35.0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height-35.0);
```

Then on NSNotification I'm trying to [self.tableView reloadData]:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doUpdateAppBefore:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

Also I'm reloading data of tableView on every UIApplicationBecomeActive notification.

Before I close my app and open it up from background to find out if it's reloads the data, I'm moving to another UIViewController and going back, which causes that somehow identifier of my self.tableView changes. I'm checking it in:

NSLog(@"Calling reloadData on : %@");

and at the beginning it gives me:

```
Calling reloadData on <UITableView: 0x9b09400;....
```

but after I segue back from another UIViewController it gives me:

```
Calling reloadData on <UITableView: 0x9b4b000;
```

which causes that it doesn't actually reload the data after I open up the app from the background state.

I've been thinking... when I segue back from another viewcontroller, viewDidLoad fires again, is it possible that it somehow sets tableView.delegate again and changes something? Just thinking...

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: If viewDidLoad fires twice, then it seems like you have a new view, hence a new tableView as well. What kind of segue are you using to get to your new view controller, and what kind of segue are you using to get back from whatever your new view controller is to your List view controller?

Comment: Well the view I'm segueing to is another ViewController that has another UITableView in it. This is the segue I'm using: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Tomorrow" sender: self]; same goes for the one that goes back, but Identifier Today, it's a modal segue

Comment: So stupid question, great tip for asking what segue do I use... I was segueing forth and back and still creating new object instead of [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a view controller, push a modal view on top of it, and then want to go back to the original view controller when you're done. So, you set up a modal segue in your storyboard, and then a second modal segue to go back. The problem is that your second modal segue doesn't return to the original view controller, but it creates a new instance of that view controller, and now your have the original view controller, the second view controller, and an unwanted third view controller. Instead of creating a segue, which creates the third view controller, you need to dismiss the second view controller, which then gets you back to your original view controller, and therefore also your original table view. So what you want to do is get rid of the second segue and replace it with an IBAction, put something like

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
```

in your .h file. Connect that to your button or whatever you're using to trigger the segue now. Then, in your implementation file, dismiss the modal view like so:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

That should get you what you want.

Alternately, and this is probably better, you can use an unwind segue as well. Go to List.h, and create this method:

```
- (IBAction)unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

Then just implement it, you can leave it blank for now. Then, drag from the button that currently triggers the segue to Exit, and select the Action Segue unwind. That will also get you back.

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a lot, I've been stuck since yesterday on this stupid thing.